# CSS drop menu disappears under the slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a site , the Home page consists of four divs , The first one contains a drop down menu , the next one contains a " slideshow " , the problem is that when I put the slide show on that div , the " drop down menu " up there disappears under the slide show when I point to it . how can I make the drop down menu being over the slideshow when I point to it !!!? I hope that you can get what I mean ...

Comment: It would be nice if you can show us your code, and reproduce your issue in a **[minimal, concrete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. Without any code and any example, it is impossible to tell what is wrong.

Comment: you can increase the z-index of the menu item and decrease the z-index of div.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set a z-index value for your dropdown menu.

For example in your css:

```
.myDropDownClass{
 z-index:1O;
}
```

And to be sure it will stay on top of the other things give them also a z-index value but less than your dropdown menu.

Hope it will help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information provided, but I will guess an answer for you.

Set the z-index of your drop-down menu and make it absolute positioned:

```
.my_submenu {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 100001;
}
```

Please provide code examples if you want more help.  Also... Heaven-forbid you are using silverlight or flash.... If you are, set wmode to transparent.

Comment: I know that the information weren't enough , I just tried to explain the issue in some easy way , anyway , your answer helped me so much , I missed the "z-index" line so the problem happened as a result , so thank you for your answer .